# why can't I get through form validation with upload files?

Tags: django, django-forms

I wrote the model like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
author = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'book/%Y/%m/%d')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/book/%s' % self.title
```

And the form:

```
class BookInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Book
```

But whatever file I choose to upload, I just can't get through the form validation, which always implies "this field is required". Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads)

Did you remember to set the form attribute enctype="multipart/form-data"